# zoom in and zoom out animation in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-animation

I have code of normally zoom in and zoom out animation between two activities, but I want something different. I have five buttons on my first activity if I click on first button then zoom in would be starts from position of first button only instead of zooming from centre. Please help me.

EDIT : Zoom should start from the button I clicked as a centre.

Comment: Your question is not quite clear, you want to zoom in from the center of the layout or, is it that your animation is not working correctly?

Comment: I have five button when I click on any button it will be expand and starting next activity.

Comment: You do not want to start a new activity?

Comment: I want start new activity also. But animation would be like expanding

Answer (score 41):

You can use this method after running the command to start your new activity,

```java
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(animation_in_goes_here,animation_out_goes_here);
```

Then you may replace your animations above, replacing the `animation_in_goes_here` with the animation resource you need for the activity that you have newly started and replacing `animation_out_goes_here` with the animation resource for the activity that you are leaving from. This will give you the switching effects.

**zoom_in.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:fillAfter="true">
    <scale
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:fromYScale="1"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="3"
    android:toYScale="3"/>
 </set>
```

**zoom_out.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:fillAfter="true">
    <scale
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="0.5"
    android:toYScale="0.5"/>
</set>
```

Hope this helped to answer your question.

Comment: thnax...but animation is not proper :(

Comment: How so what seems to be the problem?

Comment: This animation is not proper. No transition is happening with the activity I am leaving. Activity I am switching to, first zooms in and then switches back to normal. Nothing happens with the activity I am leaving. Is there any dependency I am loosing? This answer got 8 thumbs as of now so must be correct in a context.

Comment: how to make both effect in one ?

Answer (score 3):

> Zoom In

```
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromXScale="0"
    android:fromYScale="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="0.5"
    android:toYScale="0.5">

</scale>
```

> Zoom Out

```
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromXScale="2.1"
    android:fromYScale="2.1"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:startOffset="3000"
    android:toXScale="0"
    android:toYScale="0">

</scale>
```

Comment: create zoom.xml this is use for zoom out and zoom in

Comment: how to make both effect in one ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to do as follow

- Set "in" and "out" animations
- Create folder res/anim
- Put animation descriptions into res/anim folder

  `object.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.zoom_enter));
   object.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.zoom_exit));`

You can use android sdk sample animations supplied by google under Apache 2.0 licence

Or refer this which uses scaling based zooming which is easier than the former

http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html