# How To Make Drag out from zoom out of image go away?

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface, user-experience

This is My Xml Code

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".ImageViewer">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#32000000">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"

        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<!-- The primary full-screen view. This can be replaced with whatever view
     is needed to present your content, e.g. VideoView, SurfaceView,
     TextureView, etc. -->
<com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView
    android:id="@+id/Zoomage_Image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

And This is My Java Code

```
ImageView zoomage=findViewById(R.id.Zoomage_Image);
    Intent i=getIntent();
    String imageuri=i.getStringExtra("imageurl");
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: "+imageuri);
    Picasso.get().load(Uri.parse(imageuri)).into(zoomage);
```

The Zoom In Works Perfectly fine but whenever i zoom out the image leaves ugly looking drags on Screen How do i make those drag marks go out and not display.

on Some devices this drag out doesn't display while on some devices this seems very ugly.

ScreenShot

[image]

While you're on it also help me with how to add appbar layout such that it is translucent as well as provides up navigation when clicked on back button.

Comment: This may be helpfull http://codesfor.in/move-zoom-and-rotate-imageview-in-android/

Comment: @Ramees no, i think that author of that code did not know what he is doing, for example: `view.animate().rotationBy(angle).setDuration(0)` - why to use `ViewPropertyAnimator` at all? its a bad mix of using `ViewPropertyAnimator`, setting the properties directly (like `setScaleX`) and setting the layout params

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: I am confused. how to implement your way?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the library you are using try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17908984/6549598) with custom Animation and you can change any value you want as per your requirement:

Run this on your onClick:

**zoom_in.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:fillAfter="true" >
    <scale
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:fromYScale="1"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="3"
    android:toYScale="3" >
    </scale>
 </set>
```

**zoom_out.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:fillAfter="true" >
    <scale
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="0.5"
    android:toYScale="0.5" >
    </scale>
 </set>
```

Alternatively, for better understanding Try **code samples by Google** with `Zoom Animator`

[Enlarge a view using a zoom animation](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom)